# Time attendance SQL statement from to

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

we use MS SQL 2008 r2 and
we have this 2 table its for time attendance

```
 select CHECKINOUT.USERID ,USERINFO.USERID,CHECKINOUT.SENSORID,
 userinfo.BADGENUMBER,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME  
 from CHECKINOUT , userinfo 
 where CHECKINOUT.USERID=userinfo.userid 
 and userinfo.BADGENUMBER=63 and CHECKTIME 
 between '2017-03-26' and '2017-04-26'
```

---

```
    USERID  USERID  SENSORID    BADGENUMBER CHECKTIME
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-01 11:02:19.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-02 10:12:52.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-03 10:32:43.000
    181       181         1       63      2017-04-04 19:21:26.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-05 19:54:30.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-06 10:00:52.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-07 09:54:49.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-08 10:40:20.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-11 10:21:47.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-12 13:32:00.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-12 19:17:13.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-13 11:07:02.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-13 18:34:37.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-15 18:49:02.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-15 18:49:10.000
    181       181         1       63      2017-04-16 10:17:58.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-18 10:31:47.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-18 18:39:54.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-19 10:54:00.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-20 10:45:03.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-22 10:25:09.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-22 18:45:21.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-22 18:45:26.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-23 10:18:01.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-24 10:20:59.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-24 18:41:07.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-25 11:13:48.000
```

and we need to have from this 2 table check date and chick in and check out and sensor id

```
(Main(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) as Checkin , Max(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME)as  Check out )
```

first check in and last check out and the time  between Min and Max its from 6:00 AM and 5:00 AM next day its 23 hours  and the subtract between checkin and checkout as hours

for example

```
    USERID  USERID  SENSORID    BADGENUMBER CHECKTIME
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-01 10:02:19.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-01 18:12:52.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-02 10:32:43.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-03 01:21:26.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-04 10:54:30.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-04 18:00:52.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-05 09:54:49.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-05 23:40:20.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-06 10:21:47.000
    181       181         100     63      2017-04-07 03:32:00.000
```

to be like that

```
       BADGENUMBER  SENSORID  CHECKDate     Checkin   Checkout   Hours
      63         100           2017-04-01    10:02:19  18:12:52  8:10
      63         100           2017-04-02    10:32:43  01:21:26  14:49 
      63         100           2017-04-04    10:54:30  18:00:52  07:06 
      63         100           2017-04-05    09:54:49  23:40:20  13:46
      63         100           2017-04-06    10:21:47  03:32:00  17:11
```

Comment: Add the version-specific tag for the SQL version you are using. The best solution may differ by version.

Comment: Don't you have other column that determines is it in or out time?

Comment: no we determines is it in or out time by min and max from the CHECKTIME  between  6:00 AM and 5:00 AM next day

Comment: Is 5:00 AM included or not? `BETWEEN` is *usually* a terrible choice, because reports for two days in a row will **both** include a row that falls on the boundary. [See this post for more details](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: Its not make difrrent  we can say from 6am to 4 am

Answer (score 0):

This might get you the required result

```
select u.BADGENUMBER, attendance.SENSORID, attendance.CHECKDate, attendance.CheckIn ,attendance.CheckOut
,cast(DATEDIFF(n, attendance.CheckIn, attendance.checkout) / 60 as varchar) + ':' + cast(DATEDIFF(n, attendance.CheckIn, attendance.checkout) % 60 as varchar) as Minutes
from (
    select temp.USERID, temp.SENSORID, temp.CHECKDate ,temp.CheckIn
    ,case when temp.COut = temp.CheckIn then null when temp.CheckIn is null then null else temp.COut end as CheckOut
        from(
            select c.USERID, c.SENSORID, convert(date, CHECKTIME) CHECKDate
            ,(select min(CHECKTIME) from CHECKINOUT cinout where cinout.USERID = c.USERID and cinout.SENSORID = c.SENSORID and cinout.CheckTime >= dateadd(hour, 6, convert(datetime, convert(date, c.CheckTime)))) CheckIn
            ,(select max(CHECKTIME) from CHECKINOUT cinout where cinout.USERID = c.USERID and cinout.SENSORID = c.SENSORID and cinout.CheckTime <= dateadd(hour, 29, convert(datetime, convert(date, c.CheckTime)))) COut
            from CHECKINOUT c
            group by c.USERID, c.SENSORID, convert(date, CHECKTIME)
        )temp
) attendance
inner join userinfo u on u.USERID = attendance.USERID
where u.BADGENUMBER = 63 and CHECKDate 
between '2017-03-26' and '2017-04-26'
```

Comment: Please use English language

Comment: If this answer solves your problem then mark it as accepted. You can learn basic sql from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).